# MercadoPago - How to get all the payments made to a Preapproval?

Tags: java, e-commerce, mercadopago

The other day the server was down for maintenance for a couple of hours and in that interval we receive a Notification about a payment made to a Preapprobal Subscripcion (basic checkout). As our database was down, we could't store that payment.

Later that resource was block because of the lack of payment and then we realized that it was actually payed and have to manually mark it as payed.

Is there any way to get all the payments made to a preapproval by it's ID? Or at least the latest payment made? I need a way to confirm the status of a prepproval besides IPN

I couldn't find it the API docs

Answer (score 2):

I've received this answer via email from the MercadoPago team:

> Hola Sebastian, ¿Como estas?
>
> Gracias por acercarnos tu consulta.
>
> Actualmente no es posible obtener los pagos de un preapproval.
>
> Te pedimos disculpas por las molestias ocasionadas
>
> Saludos,
>
> El equipo de soporte a desarrolladores de Mercado Pago

What it says in English is that basically **it's not yet possible to obtain the payments of a preapproval**